# How to hide and show keyboard with same button

Tags: iphone, button, keyboard, uitextfield

I have `UITextField` which `becomeFirstResponder` when app starts. Then, I have a `UIButton` which `resignFirstResponder` when press it.

How to hide and show keyboard with same button? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you seem to need, the following code should have the same button both hide and show the keyboard for the textField

```
if ([textField isFirstResponder]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
} else {
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

**edit**
<strike>You can also put in code to alter the title of the button in the if loop.</strike>
The appropriate place to put the code to alter the title of the button would in the textField's delegate methods `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `-textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Comment: How do you expect the button to behave?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
        button.selected = !button.selected;
        if (button.selected) {
            // show the keyboard.
            [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        }else {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytest.h

IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton

- (IBAction) showHideKeyBoard:(id)sender;

mytest.m

-(IBAction) showHideKeyBoard:(id) sender {

        if (myButton.selected) {
            // show the keyboard.
            [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            [myButton setTitle:@"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            myButton.selected = NO;
        }else {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
            [myButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            myButton.selected = YES;
        }
}
```

Comment: Button is never selected. Will always hide the keyboard !?